# Loop over list of DataFrame names and save to csv in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to save a bunch of PySpark DataFrames as csv tables. The tables should also have the same names as the DataFrames.
The code should be something like that:

```
for table in ['ag01','a5bg','h68chl', 'df42', 'gh63', 'ur55', 'ui99']:
    ppath='hdfs://hadoopcentralprodlab01/..../data/'+table+'.csv'
    table.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(ppath)
```

The problem is here that in the command "table.repartition(1)..." I need the actual names of data frames without ''. So in this form the code doesn't work. But If write "for table in [ag01,a5bg,...]", so without quotes in the list, I then cannot define the path because I cannot concantenate the name of data frame and a string. How can I resolve this dilemma?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a bunch of variable names not considered good coding practice. You should have used a list or a dictionary in the first place. But if you're stuck in this already, you can use `eval` to get the dataframe stored in that variable.

```
for table in ['ag01', 'a5bg', 'h68chl', 'df42', 'gh63', 'ur55', 'ui99']:
    ppath = 'hdfs://hadoopcentralprodlab01/..../data/'+table+'.csv'
    df = eval(table)
    df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(ppath)
```

Comment: [`asteval`](https://pypi.org/project/asteval/) is a better alternative for `eval` and can offer some protection against malicious code injection.

Comment: What is the purpose of `eval` here?

Comment: @MykolaZotko that's for getting the dataframe from the variable name as a string. It's not a good practice in general. Dictionaries would be more appropriate, e.g. `{'ag01': df1, ...}`.